# Configuración correcta de Heroku para despliegue usando Django tenant schemas

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

Uso el servicio de Heroku para desplegar mis aplicaciones, hasta ahora sin problema alguno. El problema surgió al implementar la arquitectura **multi tenancy** usando *django-tenant-schemas*.
Funciona a la perfección en mi computador local, creando un *schema* independiente para cada *tenant* (empresa que usa mi aplicación) y esto me ha facilitado inmensamente los querys y la gestión en general.

Este es mi archivo *settings.py*:

```py
"""
Django settings for kinetfood project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'h^#ud((x^2weqh9+5jdzt4v&0p0)f@a_iq@yi6go+(6=@_9x5='

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# Application definition
##APLICACIONES COMPARTIDAS##
SHARED_APPS = [

    'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory
    'empresas',  # you must list the app where your tenant model resides in
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'import_export',
    'bootstrap4',
    'usuarios',
    'impuestos',
    'medidas',

]

TENANT_APPS = [
    'app',
    'productos',
    'ventas',
    'reservas',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]

TENANT_MODEL = "empresas.Empresa" # app.Model
TENANT_DOMAIN_MODEL = "empresas.Domain" # app.Model

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'tenant_schemas.middleware.TenantMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URL_CONF = 'kinetfood.public_urls'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'kinetfood.urls'

##
EMPRESA_ACTIVA= 'Default'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'kinetfood.context_processors.get_empresa_activa',
                'kinetfood.context_processors.set_empresa_activa',
            ],
        },
    },
]
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    #...
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kinetfood.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'tenant_schemas.postgresql_backend',
        'NAME': 'kinetfood',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin123', #PW JORGE
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',

    }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
    'tenant_schemas.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Guayaquil'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Mi modelo tenant *empresas*:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
###tenant###
from tenant_schemas.models import TenantMixin
###endTenant###
# Create your models here.

class Empresa(TenantMixin):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Nombre de su empresa.')
    slogan = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Frase Slogan de su negocio.')
    gerente = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    descripcion = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Describa el campo ocupacional y área de su empresa.')
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    nro_mesas = models.IntegerField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    sitio_web = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Página web de su empresa.')

    auto_create_schema= True

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Empresa"
        verbose_name_plural = "Empresas"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Es la configuración completa de mi *settings* y funciona en un entorno local. Sólo fue necesario adicionalmente configurar el archivo de hosts en mi directorio de windows y listo, funcionan todos los *tenants* que vaya creando con su respectiva url.

Al momento de hacer un push a **Heroku** lo hace sin errores. Pero al momento de ejecutar las migraciones con el comando: `heroku run python manage.py migrate_schemas --shared` me arroja el siguiente error en la consola de heroku `heroku logs --tail`:

```
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>  
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)  
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line  
utility.execute()  
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute  
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)  
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv  
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)  
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute  
output = self.handle(*args, **options)  
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tenant_schemas/management/commands/migrate_schemas.py", line 42, in handle  
executor.run_migrations(tenants=[self.schema_name])  
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tenant_schemas/migration_executors/base.py", line 58, in run_migrations  
run_migrations(self.args, self.options, self.codename, public_schema_name)  
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tenant_schemas/migration_executors/base.py", line 30, in run_migrations  
connection.set_schema(schema_name)  
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__  
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)  
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'set_schema' 
Process exited with status 1
```

He revisado la mayoría de documentación de *Heroku Postgres*, actualizado mi plan de Postgres a *tier Hobby*, he tratado de implementar otras configuraciones en el *settings*, eliminar algunos módulos de mis apps en el *requirements.txt*, pero nada, sigue arrojando el mismo error; ya no sé que más hacer.

Este es mi *requirements.txt*:

```
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.9.142
botocore==1.12.142
diff-match-patch==20181111
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.1.3
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-bootstrap4==0.0.7
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-import-export==1.1.0
django-storages==1.7.1
django-tenant-schemas==1.9.0
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
docutils==0.14
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
jdcal==1.4
jmespath==0.9.4
libsass==0.16.0
odfpy==1.3.6
openpyxl==2.5.11
Pillow==5.3.0
psycopg2-binary==2.7.6.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2018.7
PyYAML==3.13
s3transfer==0.2.0
six==1.11.0
static3==0.7.0
tablib==0.12.1
unicodecsv==0.14.1
urllib3==1.24.3
virtualenv==15.1.0
whitenoise==4.1.1
xlrd==1.1.0
xlwt==1.3.0
```

Si alguien ha conseguido hacer un despliegue correcto hacia Heroku usando **Django multi tenancy** agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Saludos y buenos despliegues!

Comment: Puedes agregar tu modelo,  para crear un modelo debes hacer algo como `from tenant_schemas.models import TenantMixin` y luego el modelo debe ser algo como `class modelo(TenantMixin): ......`

Comment: Listo, agregaré el modelo que tengo. Mi modelo si hereda de `TenantMixin`. Funciona bien la creación de tenants usando la shell de django en mi pc local, al subir a Heroku lanza el error en la consola de `heroku logs --tail`. Gracias @JackNavaRow

Comment: te funciono lo comentado? es otro error ahorra?

Comment: @JackNavaRow el error es el mismo, la herencia desde _TenantMixin_ estaba correctamente configurada pues funciona bien en local. Probaré haciendo un pdb en _tenant_schemas/migration_executors/base.py_ para ver si doy con la variable que no encuentra. Ya me estoy frustrando.

Comment: intenta `python manage.py migrate_schemas --list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas Heroku te recomiendo trabajar con variables de configuración. Para ese caso la solución es esta:
Tienes que desactivar la configuración por defecto de la base de datos de Heroku (django_heroku) pasando `databases=False` a la función de configuración y reconfigurando la base de datos manualmente. Es decir, reemplazar la linea que recomienda Heroku `django_heroku.settings(locals())` por lo siguiente:

```
import django_heroku
# Activate Django-Heroku without database setup.
config = locals()
django_heroku.settings(config, databases=False)
# Manual configuration of database
import dj_database_url
conn_max_age = config.get('CONN_MAX_AGE', 600)  # Used in django-heroku
config['DATABASES'] = {
    'default': dj_database_url.parse(
        os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'),    
        engine='tenant_schemas.postgresql_backend',
        conn_max_age=conn_max_age,
        ssl_require=True,
    )
}
```

en donde `DATABASE_URL`es el nombre de la base de datos definida en tu panel de `Heroku>settings>Config Vars`

[info sobre django_heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration)

Comment: Mil gracias @Marcelo. Funcionó de maravilla. Subí esta configuración a Heroku y pude ejecutar el script `heroku run python manage.py migrate_schemas --shared` y ya no lanzó ningún error, luego sólo tuve que ejecutar la creación de tenants que adjuntaré a continuación. Gracias por la ayuda, servirá para muchos de ahora en adelante.

Comment: Tienes alguna idea de cómo crear los dominios en heroku para los diferentes tenants? Gracias.

Comment: @JoseLuisQuichimbo Esa es otra pregunta y probablemente te enfrentes a otros problemas. Lo que buscas es configurar un dominio comodín y la info de Heroku es esta: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-wildcard-domain
Existen ciertas restricciones para estos dominios de parte de Heroku y de tu proveedor de dominios, si tienes otra pregunta referente a este tema te recomiendo abras otro hilo.